# Instead of printing each element in tuple, Python prints letters

Tags: python, list, tuples

I try to create a validator by getting data from MySQL. After getting data from MySQL, I have a list containing 2 tuples. But when I tried to printing elements in tuples, instead of printing elements from the tuple, my code printed the letter of each of them. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from mysqlconnect import my_connect
from mysqlconnect import my_cursor


mysql_get_all_user_information_query = "SELECT user_name, user_password FROM USER_INFORMATION"
my_cursor.execute(mysql_get_all_user_information_query)
all_information_record = list(my_cursor.fetchall())


def validator_username_password():
    global all_information_record

    username = entry_username.get()
    password = entry_password.get()

    if username == "" and password == "":
        messagebox.showinfo("", "Blank Field Are Not Allowed")
    for user_record in all_information_record:
        for user_name_pass in user_record:
            print(user_name_pass[0])
            print(user_name_pass[1])
            if username == user_name_pass[0] and password == user_name_pass[1]:
                messagebox.showinfo("", "Login Success")
                root.destroy()
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("", "Incorrent Username and Password")
```

Here is the output (I have **account1:** admin, password: 123456
and **account2:** admin123, password: 123456):
[image]

Thank all of you so much!!!

Edit: When I use only 1 for loop, I get 2 tuples.
[image]

Comment: i don't know about the strategy of putting your passwords on the web. the problem with the code is if you iterate over a list, and then iterate over the strings in that list that's what's going to happen: a letter by letter display.

Comment: After fetching data from database, I get a list containing 2 tuples. And I iterate over a list to get tuples, and then over tuples to get elements including username & password.

Comment: the second iteration you don't need, you can access the username and password in the first iteration. nested for loops are usually a performance issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

You explained your situation in the comments yourself. You are no longer having tuples, but you are still indexing it. IMO, you do not need nested loops(even proves your logic wrong), here is an example on checking username and password(non-`tkinter` example):

```
lst = [('u1','p1'),('u2','p2')]

def login():
    for item in lst:
        u_name = item[0]
        p_name = item[1]
        if u_name == username and p_name == password:
            print('Successfully logged in')
            break
        else:
            print('Wrong credential')
            break

username = 'u1'
password = 'p1'

login()
```